# Unity3D - Object will disappear when looking directly too it or too close

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, 3d-modelling

Both hand with disappear in the game and scene if i get close enough or look at them any solution. m using unity URP:
it only happens when using animation rigging

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bounding boxes (i.e Bounds) of your SkinnedMeshRenderers are set to correct dimensions. Culling decisions are made based on those boxes. If they are too small, the mesh might get culled even if it's still visible.

You can also check "Update When Off Screen" to have the bounds updated while animating. This does come at a slight performance cost however, so see if it's suitable for you.